# Migrating data to a ManyToMany Field in django

Tags: django, migration

There already exists a model called Team and an email field users.
Later it is converted to a ManyToMany Field. Is it possible to migrate the data from the email field to the ManyToMany field by scripts. Currently the users list is saved in the string format. I tried by converting it to the list format and then adding it to the ManyToMany field.

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = model.EmailField()

class Team(models.Model):
    users = models.EmailField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='teams')
```

And I tried with the following code to restore the data, but it is not getting restored

```
def team_member_update(apps, schema_editor):
    team_list = Team.objects.all()
    for team in team_list:
        list_users = team.users
        # converting to list 
        for user in list_users:
            team_user = User.objects.create(email=list_users)
            team.members.add(team_user)
            team.save()
```

Comment: If `Team.users` is an `EmailField` won't it contain just a single email address? Iterating over a string (the email) will return a single character at a time

Comment: The list of users got saved in it in the string format. It is possible to do the conversion and the user object creation, but it is getting added to the team instance `team.members.add(team_user)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small modif

```
def team_member_update(apps, schema_editor):
    teams = Team.objects.all()
    for team in teams:
        # Here maybe you need to convert the string in a list
        # If the string is the form 'email@g.com,email2@g.com'
        list_users = team.users.strip().split(',')

        for user_email in list_users:
            if user_email != '':
                team_user = User.objects.create(email=user_email)
                team.members.add(team_user)
            else:
                print('user_email is empty')
        
        # Team.save() must be outside the loop in list_users
        team.save()
```

According to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), it is possible to simplify it :

```
       for user_email in list_users:
            if user_email != '':
                print(f'email used is {user_email})
                team.members.create(email=user_email)
            else:
                print('user_email is empty')
        
        # Team.save() must be outside the loop in list_users
        team.save()
```

If this is not working (according to your comments), I think the problem is with the emails.

Comment: No issues with the conversion. I have users list in the `list type` itself. Adding the data to the many to many field `members` is not happening.

Comment: I made a correction. team.save() was at a wrong place. And you need to confirm that the creation of the team_user is done and accepted

Comment: Thanks @Henri. Also I tried printing `team.members` after `team.save()` and then it is showing like `User.None` which means the updated data is not saved to the instance.

Comment: Another proposition. If it is not working, check with printing your emails.